# Add total length of albums (FLAC Format songs) into name of each folder

Tags: linux, bash, flac

Thanks for accepting me :)

I'm making a project to order a lot of album of my collection and I'm classifying the albums by their complete length, currently I am doing it manually but it is quite tedious. I would like to see if it is possible to create a script in linux that allows you to navigate through each folder, determine the total duration of the album and later add that duration in the final part of the folder name.

The general structure of the albums I have is like this:

```
Album1
   >|Disk1
       >SONG1.FLAC
       >SONG2.FLAC
       >SONG3.FLAC
   >|Disk2
       >SONG1.FLAC
       >SONG2.FLAC
       >SONG3.FLAC

 Album2
   >|Disk1
       >SONG1.FLAC
       >SONG2.FLAC
       >SONG3.FLAC
   >|Disk2
       >SONG1.FLAC
       >SONG2.FLAC
       >SONG3.FLAC
```

My idea is that the script determines the total duration of Album1 and Album2 and of all albums that are in the same folder and that also the duration, if possible in this format [minutes: seconds] add it as the album name, for example:

```
Album1[minutes:second]
Album2[minutes:second]
```

If the duration of the album exceeds one hour, it would be possible to convert it into minutes, for example:
1 hour: 36 minutes: 13 seconds >>>> 96 minutes and 13 seconds

I hope you can help me a bit :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that requires `bash` and `exiftool` to be installed on the system:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -euo pipefail

# Iterate over all directories containing flac files
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 dirname -z | xargs -0 -L1 dirname | sort -u | while read -r ALBUM; do
    # In each directory, iterate over all flac files
    # and accumulate the duraction to build the final album name

    NEW_NAME="$(find "$ALBUM" -type f -name '*.flac' | while read -r FLAC; do
        # Determine duration of audio using the exiftool
        exiftool "$FLAC" | grep -E '^Duration' | sed -E 's#^.*: ##' | tr ':' ' '
    done | awk -v ALBUM="$ALBUM" '
    { total_minutes += $1 * 60 } # Accumulate hours
    { total_minutes += $2 }      # Accumulate minutes
    { total_seconds += $3 }      # Accumulate seconds
    END {
        total_minutes += int(total_seconds / 60)
        total_seconds = total_seconds % 60
        printf "%s[%d:%d]", ALBUM, total_minutes, total_seconds
    }
    ')"

    echo mv "$ALBUM" "$NEW_NAME"
done
```

Short explanation: It recursively finds all flac files in the current directory, groups them by their parent parent directory (i.e. not disk but album directory) and then iterates over all album directories. For each album directory, it accumulates the duration of all flac files found in that directory using awk. awk is also used to build the new name of the album.

The given solution only echos the mv's. If you are happy with the results, remove the `echo` and just keep the `mv ...`.

Please note that while the script worked for me locally, it's possible that there are edge cases in your file structure. I would suggest you to do a backup first.

Comment: Thanks for provide to me the code, but I got errors:

'args: unmatched single quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option´

Comment: You're welcome. Can you elaborate on how you executed the script? Did you put it in a file and run it using `bash filename`? I just tested it on another machine and it works there as well.

Comment: Apparently, xargs has a weird quirk in that it doesn't like it if you have filenames containing single quotes (') which you probably have. I have updated the script, please test again.

Comment: Thanks for you help.
at the moment I have the script outside the albums that I have, for example

Collection
     |____Album1
               |_Disk1
               |_Disk2
     |____Album2
               |_Disk1
               |_Disk2
     |____script.sh

I've executed the script and I got this message:

mv . .[59:48]

It shows correclty the lengh of one of those album but doesnt show the complete name of the album name, also only can analyze one album instead the two.

Comment: You probably executed the script while inside an album directory. Run the script from the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks, please check my latest answer, i've detailed better

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "only can analyze one album instead the two".  

Regarding the complete name of the album: You need to run the script in the parent directory containing all your albums, i.e. `cd MySongs/; bash script.sh`.  

If that still doesn't help: Do you mind sharing your directory structure so we know what exactly you are talking about? You can dump it by running `find . -name '*.flac' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 dirname | sort -u > dump.txt` and upload it to a paste service like pastebin.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the moment the script is working because I modified the script to this part `find . -name '*.flac' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 dirname | sort -u`

Also here's my results of the dump:

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the moment the script is working because I modified the script to this part `find . -name '*.flac' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 dirname | sort -u`

Also here's my results of the dump:
[link](https://pastebin.pl/view/693a23e9) 

the only problem still persist is that the `ALBUM` can't get the folder album name, in the echo command shows the 'ALBUM` like as `.` and not the full name:
https://pastebin.pl/view/82cfd827

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for shilch user who can help me with his script how to add total lengh in echa album, but i made some new modification that

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -euo pipefail
# Iterate over all directories containing flac files
# Iterate over all directories containing flac files
for d in */ ; do
    a=$d
    z="$(basename "$d")"
    cd "$d"
    # In each directory, iterate over all flac files
    # and accumulate the duraction to build the final album name
    NEW_NAME="$(find . -type f -name '*.flac' | while read -r FLAC; do
        # Determine duration of audio using the exiftool
        exiftool "$FLAC" | grep -E '^Duration' | sed -E 's#^.*: ##' | tr ':' ' '
    done | awk -v ALBUM="$ALBUM" '
    { total_minutes += $1 * 60 } # Accumulate hours
    { total_minutes += $2 }      # Accumulate minutes
    { total_seconds += $3 }      # Accumulate seconds
    END {
        total_minutes += int(total_seconds / 60)
        total_seconds = total_seconds % 60
        printf "%s[%d:%d]", ALBUM, total_minutes, total_seconds
    }
    ')"
    #echo "$d"
    cd -
    echo "$z"
    b="$NEW_NAME"
    c=$z$b
    echo "$c"
    echo "$NEW_NAME"
    #echo mv "$ALBUM" "$NEW_NAME"
    mv -- "$z" "$c"
    #mv "$z" "$c"
done
```

But this has a problem, when it analyzes songs that are less than 59 seconds long, it does not add the seconds correctly and takes the value of the second as if it were minutes, and the calculation does not give the exact value, for example, this album has a song that only lasts 27 seconds, for example:

```
 exiftool *.flac | grep -E '^Duration'
Duration                        : 0:00:56
Duration                        : 0:05:27
Duration                        : 0:03:50
Duration                        : 0:05:06
Duration                        : 0:03:48
Duration                        : 0:00:41
Duration                        : 0:08:18
Duration                        : 0:04:02
Duration                        : 0:16:20
Duration                        : 0:06:59
Duration                        : 0:06:02
Duration                        : 0:03:51
Duration                        : 0:05:05
Duration                        : 0:16:53
Duration                        : 27.01 s
Duration                        : 0:04:20
Duration                        : 0:03:29
Duration                        : 0:07:14
```

in this case it only lasts 27 seconds, but it does not show the minutes or the hour in 00 format, it is a exiftool issue. I've tried using soxi and they got the correclty lengh but doesnt work using this script.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the individual durations in seconds by using the right options with your tool of choice.

To get the duration in seconds:

- with `exiftool` :
  `exiftool -b -Duration "$file"`
- with `mediainfo` :
  `mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%Duration%" "$file"`
  This will output milliseconds, so you will have to divide by 1000.

After having added the values in seconds, you can convert them back to your preferred time format.

For example:

```
total=0
for file in "/your/flac/directory"/*.flac; do
    length=$( mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%Duration%" "$file" )
    (( total += length ))
done
(( total /= 1000 )) # from milliseconds to seconds
echo "Total: $total seconds"
date -u -d "@$total" +%H:%M:%S
```

Or if you want to include subdirectories and use `find` :

```
total=0
find "$your_directory" -name "*.flac" | \
{
   while read file; do
      length=$( mediainfo --Inform="Audio;%Duration%" "$file" )
      (( total += length ))
    done
  (( total /= 1000 )) # from milliseconds to seconds
  echo "Total: $total seconds"
  date -u -d "@$total" +%H:%M:%S
}
```

These example use mediainfo and it's milliseconds output to take advantage of the built-in Bash arithmetic operations. If using exiftool, which outputs decimals, you would need to either use `bc` or something else for the additions, or remove the decimals before doing the additions

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have written the script again with some help from the users who have written here and in the end I have done this with the help of the `shntool` program, which I found that the total of the songs is more exact than using `exiftool`. Also this ways is much more faster than exiftool:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */ ; do
    a=$d
    z="$(basename "$d")"
    cd "$d"
    var=$(find * -name "*.flac" | shntool len  | tail -n1 | tr ':' '.'| sed 's/^[ t]*//' | cut -d "." -f 1,2 )
    cd -
    echo "[$var]"
    echo "$z"
    c=$z$"[$var]"
    echo "$c"
    mv -- "$z" "$c"
done
```